# DrawString ignores tabs when using overload with StringFormat

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing

I have a form which reads the text from a textbox and then draws it with the `DrawString` method from `System.Drawing.Graphics`.

Depending on which overload I use, the result is different. The overload that expects a additional `StringFormat` seems to ignore tabs. The overload without `StringFormat` works just fine.

The result looks like this:

[image]

This is the code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.AcceptsTab = true;
        textBox1.Multiline = true;
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        { 
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            Font font = new Font("Arial", 20);

            StringFormat format = StringFormat.GenericDefault;
            format.Trimming = StringTrimming.None;

            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), new Point(10, 50), new Point(10, 140));

            g.DrawString(textBox1.Text, font, Brushes.Black, new Point(10,60));
            g.DrawString(textBox1.Text, font, Brushes.Black, new Point(10,100), format);

        }
    }
```

It seems that I could set the TabStops manually by calling `format.SetTabStops()`, but thats not a preferred solution.

I tried to set `format.Trimming = StringTrimming.None` but that doesn`t work.

Is there a possibility to print the tabs from the text while using the `StringFormat` overload?

Comment: That's what it takes.  You however should be using TextRenderer.DrawText() instead, it causes many fewer surprises.  Stops you from having to fret about tabs as well, it just takes TextFormatFlags.ExpandTabs without having to be explicit.

Comment: @Hans: the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says: _The default number of characters per tab is eight._ I couldn't find if and how this can be changed to either a different default (in en units?) or better, set individual stops?

Comment: DRAWTEXTPARAMS.iTabLength in the winapi, the .NET wrapper doesn't expose it.

Comment: @HansPassant Just drawing with `TextRenderer` on a form seems to work. But as soon as I draw in a `PrintDocument` it draws nothing. Am I missing something here?

Comment: TextRenderer is appropriate for windows, for a printer you *do* need Graphics.DrawString().  At which point you ought to be a lot more interested in tabulating your output correctly so it looks decent on paper.  Not something you'd want to leave up to SetTabStops(), blow past one tab stop and the printout looks pretty horrible.

Comment: But then I can´t use the overload with StringFormat can I? It was just a simplified example, but in the real application I have to use StringFormat to set the Alignment in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it looks like design fallacy of [`Graphics.DrawString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx) — with having less-detailed overload and more-detailed overload, e.g.:

```
DrawString(String, Font, Brush, PointF)
DrawString(String, Font, Brush, PointF, StringFormat)
```

— it doesn't allow the more-detailed overload to be called in a way that fully resembles the behavior of the less-detailed overload.

For example:

- calling `graphics.DrawString(…, new StringFormat())` will make all tabs zero-width;
- calling `var stringFormat = new StringFormat(); stringFormat.SetTabStops(0, new float[] { 8 }); graphics.DrawString(…, stringFormat)` will make all tabs to have width of 8 pixels, not 8 spaces;
- of course, you can mangle something like `var stringFormat = new StringFormat(); stringFormat.SetTabStops(0, new float[] { Font.SizeInPoints / 2 * e.Graphics.DpiX / 72 * 8 }); graphics.DrawString(…, stringFormat)` — **de facto it works** (the specified tab-width coincides with the tab-width of `StringFormat`-less `DrawString`-call; last item in the `float[]` array is applied to all further tabs) — but no parts of documentation guarantee that it won't change in future.

Of course, technically calling a `StringFormat`-less `DrawString` overload is equivalent to passing `null` into `StringFormat` parameter — but that doesn't help in practice (e.g. if you want to specify some of `StringFormat` properties, but keep default tab-behavior).